# Try/Catch skipping loops?

Tags: java

I recently started reading up on try/catch and understand them to a certain degree so I thought i'd give it a try.

The program I am writing asks you for an double and stores it in an array but if the input is not a double it says 'please enter a double' but if you enter not a double in more than once then the program terminate and adds up all the double values entered.

If i enter lets just say "fdsaf" in then I get

> Please input a double
>
> Please input an double
>
> Please input a double
>
> 0.0

package task4;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Double> fPoint = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double holder = 0;
    
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
    
        while(i < 2){
            try{
                System.out.println("Please input an double");
        
                double temp = in.nextDouble();      
                fPoint.add(temp);
        
            }catch( InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Please input a double");
                i++;
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < fPoint.size(); j++){
            holder +=  fPoint.get(j);
        }
        System.out.println(holder);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well the if I enter 'sdjgf' then the loop wont loop over a second time, the user has to have a second chance to enter a double @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 0):

Your program's usage of the `Scanner` API is broken. Please read its documentation carefully. I will point one crucial sentence:

> When a scanner throws an `InputMismatchException`, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

All you do in this case is call the *same* method again, resulting in an infinite loop. Typically you will want to call

```
in.nextLine();
```

within the catch-block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not so much the `try...catch` as it is the way a `Scanner` works.

A `Scanner` keeps around a "look ahead" buffer that allows it to have methods like `hasNextInt()`, `hasNextDouble()` etc.

When one of its methods, like `nextDouble()`, is called, it reads the input from its source (`System.in`) in this case into this "look ahead" buffer, and checks whether it is compatible with what the user asked for. If not, the input stays in the buffer, and the `Scanner` throws an exception. (If the method was `hasNextDouble()` then it won't throw an exception, just return false).

This can be helpful in some situations. For example, if the programmer wants to try first to see if the next item in the input is an int, then if it's not, to see if it's a double, then if not, to see if it's a string that matches some pattern - the programmer can do that, because the data is still waiting in that buffer, and will not be thrown away until it is properly read by any `nextXXX()` method.

But this behavior makes the program fail, because you expected that double to be gone, and so you expected the program to read the next input. But it doesn't, because you didn't get rid of the old input, and it's still waiting in the buffer.

Each time you call `nextDouble()`, it looks at this buffer, which didn't change, and sees that it's *still* not a double, and it keeps it there and throws an exception again. Your `i` increments, you reach `2` and you exit your program, although you only tried one input item.

So, as you were told, you nead to clear the buffer before you do the retry. To do this, you can use `nextLine()`. Because it doesn't expect any particular input and will accept anything, it will certainly remove that bad input from the buffer. In fact, it will remove everything until the end of the input line.

Put it in your `catch` block. Once you do that, your loop will work properly, by reading your next real input.